# Angular JS and Laravel (Single Page Application with Localization on URL)

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angular-ui, single-page-application, angular-translate

Is it possible in angular js to create an url with localization while doing a single page app.

I'm using angularjs, angular-translate and angular-ui-router for front-end and laravel for backend

e.g.

```
www.domain.com/en/#!/login - english
www.domain.com/kr/#!/login - korean
www.domain.com/#!/login - english
```

Are there any examples?

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 2+ there is a library **localize-router**. You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localize-router). Maybe this helps.